# Something is wrong with this code

Tags: java

**My homework assignment says "Write a program that reads a file and writes a copy of the file to another file with line numbers inserted" I have this code but something's wrong, can anyone help please? Thank you in advance**

ShowFile:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

class ShowFile {

public static void main(final String args[])

throws IOException

{
    int i;

    FileInputStream fin;

    try {

        fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]);

    } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("File Not Found");

        return;

    } catch (final ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

        System.out.println("Usage: ShowFile File");

        return;
    }

    do {

        i = fin.read();

        if (i != -1)
            System.out.print((char) i);

    } while (i != -1);

    fin.close();

}
}
```

CopyFile:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class CopyFile {

public static void main(final String args[])

throws IOException

{
    int i;

    FileInputStream fin;

    FileOutputStream fout;

    try {

        // open input file

        try {

            fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]);

        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Input File Not Found");

            return;

        }

        // open output file

        try {

            fout = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);

        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Error Opening Output File");

            return;

        }
    } catch (final ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

        System.out.println("Usage: CopyFile From To");

        return;

    }

    // Copy File

    try {

        do {

            i = fin.read();

            if (i != -1)
                fout.write(i);

        } while (i != -1);

    } catch (final IOException e) {

        System.out.println("File Error");

    }

    fin.close();

    fout.close();

}
}
```

This is the error message-

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: C 
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C 
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) 
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) 
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) 
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) 
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: And the problem would be ??

Comment: @Slink Keep it simple, you can try the code given below.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ...

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("infile"));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outfile"));
String line;
int lineNumber = 0;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    writer.write(++lineNumber + " " + line);
    writer.newLine();
}
writer.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this and I get an error saying BufferedReader cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: Did you import the required classes?

Comment: @Sudhanshu - It is a bad idea to give students code so that they don't have to do their own homework.  Especially since the REAL problem seems to be nothing to do with the student's code.

Comment: Agree. Anyway, was just trying to help showing the better way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem must be in the way that you are running the program.  The exception seems to be saying that it can't find a class called "C".

My guess is that you have supplied the name of the class to be executed as a pathname not as a classname.  Please read the manual page for the `java` command carefully.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code.
I think you just have passing wrong argument.

Let say you have this readme.txt in your drive,
you must run this, like this :

```
java ShowFile "C:\readme.txt"
```